# How can we write క్ష (Telugu language) unicode (combining the "ka" & "sha" grapheme) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

'\u0C15' is the unicode for "ka", but we need to combine this with "sha" to make "ksha".

Comment: what specific problem are you having?

Comment: Looks like that character is 3 characters: `c15 TELUGU LETTER KA`, 
`c4d TELUGU SIGN VIRAMA` and `c37 TELUGU LETTER SSA`

Comment: So I guess the answer is you write it like this `const myString = "\u0C15\u0C4D\u0C37"` or like this `const myString = "క్ష"`

Comment: You are asking for ligatures. Your font should do it, if you have ka+sha. Note: the results may be language specific (so check that you set the correct language). To force one way or the other, you may use ZWJ (and ZWNJ)